# Linux shell script: Renaming files according to directory name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a sh/bash script to rename files according to directory names. For example if there is a directory named Linux, the files inside should be renamed Linux.jpg, Linux2.jpg, Linux3.jpg etc. There is also more then 1 directory within the main example directory with other files also.

it must work within my copy script if possible, i am copying the directory across to another folder, then when that is done i'd like the rename process to happen. Here is my copy script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if cp -r "$1" "$2"
then echo "copy success!"
else echo "copy failed!"
fi
```

Comment: Can you give us an example directory tree before and after the rename?

Comment: /root/linux/dddd.jpg,ddff.jpg,ffks.jpg turns into /root/linux/linux.jpg, linux2.jpg, linux3.jpg

Comment: i have tried numerous things which simply have not worked / not had the desired results.. I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

It seems this question is already answered here, please check it out:
[Shell script to rename files based on directory names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181073/rename-files-based-on-directory-names)

Comment: perhaps i was using it incorrectly, but this code renamed a whole bunch of undesired files and folders! Is there a simpler/more efficient way?